# $routeProvider not working with html5Mode

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I just start to learn angularJs, and was trying to configure the partial page with angular route service.

It worked with the hash format, however，when I tried to get rid of hash, the routeProvider stopped working.

JS

```
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider.when("/", { templateUrl: "/index.html" }).
        when("/about", { templateUrl: "/partials/about.html" }).
        when("/contact", { templateUrl: "/partials/contact.html" }).
        otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
});
```

HTML

```
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
              <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul
```

Can someone enlighten me?

Comment: How did it _stop working_? Does clicking on the links do nothing now? Does it cause a 404? Does it produce any messages on the error console?

Comment: No content in ng-view part. Can not load the partial page

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to change

```
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

to

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
```

And add

```
<base href="/">
```

in a document "head" section.