# Express - enabling catch all for Angular 1.x html5Mode with multiple router files is not working

Tags: angularjs, express-router, html5mode

Okay so this question originates from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61423585/angular-1-routeprovider-not-working-in-html5mode) post, which is also my question but sorta moved onto this problem.

Now the problem is, my angular app works but when it comes to Node routes, like **/login**, the browser thinks it's an Angular route. The browser does detect it as a Node route when I refresh the whole page but not when I am navigating the site once Angular routing has kicked in.

Long story short, here are my route files:

```
require('./routes/routes.js')(express, app);
require('./routes/default.js')(express, app);
```

routes.js file:

```
module.exports = function(express, app){
    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('index');
    });

    router.get('/login', function(req, res){
        if (req.isAuthenticated()){
            res.render('index');
        } else {
            res.render('login');
        }
});
```

default.js:

```
module.exports = function(express, app, passport, Promise){
    var defaultRouter = express.Router();

    defaultRouter.get('/*', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('./views/index.html');
    });
};
```

Your help will be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave up on making this work on the root URL so I added **/index** to the **baseURL** like this:

**index.html** file:

```
<head>
  <base href="/index/">
</head>
```

The, I added a catch all to the **routes.js** file, as below:

```
module.exports = function(express, app){
    var router = express.Router();

    router.get('*', function(req, res, next) {
        if(req.url == '/' || req.url == '/login'){
            next();
        } else {
            res.sendfile('./views/index.html');
        }
    });


    router.get('/', function(req, res){
        res.render('index');
    });

    router.get('/login', function(req, res){
        if (req.isAuthenticated()){
            res.render('index');
        } else {
            res.render('login');
        }
});
```

With the angular file of course having this:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode({
    enabled: true,
    requireBase: true
}).hashPrefix('');
```

And there. It works like a charm now.

I hope this helps whoever are in my shoes.